# Как вывести в терминал права доступа к файлу для пользователя?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, chmod

Всем доброго времени суток) У меня такой вопрос. Как выводить в терминал права доступа к конкретному файлу для конкретно указаного пользователя? Перерыл пол интернета но как ни странно штатной команды так и не нашел. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `ls -l ./path/to/file` чем-то не подходит?

Comment: Не потходит т.к. в команде нужно указать конкретного пользователя или пару пользователей

Comment: пример добавь вопрос, какие права на файл, что ты хочешь указать и что получить на выходе...

Comment: Сначала спрашивает про конкретного пользователя, а потом говорит "не подходит", потому что нужно указывать конкретного пользователя. Чудной.

Comment: На входе мне нужно указать имя файла и пользователя(или пару пользователей) , а на выходе я должен получить подробную информацию об уровнях доступа к файлу для каждого из указаных пользователей. Как то так.

Comment: расшифруйте, пожалуйста, что именно ваш преподаватель подразумевает под «подробной информацией об уровнях доступа».

Comment: @Serhiy, если я правильно понял, ты пытаешься получить что-то подобное информации из `access (2)` для произвольного пользователя? AFAIK с полной достоверностью запросить это нет возможности (по крайней мере какого-либо похожего системного вызова в linux я не нашёл), соответственно нет и утилиты, которая могла бы достоверно проверить это. Остаётся писать только какой-нить костылик...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Спасибо вам. Так и сделаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в принципе, абсолютно точный ответ на вопросы «читабелен/писабелен/исполнябелен ли данный файл» даёт, например, программа `/usr/bin/test`, запущенная с соответствующей опцией (`-r/-w/-x`).

одно лишь изучение, например, вывода программы *ls/stat/и т.п.* не может дать **абсолютно точного ответа**, т.к. помимо базовых атрибутов (осложняющихся вычислением групповой принадлежности пользователя), есть ещё всякие *acl*-и, *selinux*-контексты и т.д. и т.п.

проблема в том, что данные проверки производятся (естественно) лишь для [*euid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Effective_user_ID), от имени которого вызвана программа `/usr/bin/test`.

потому, чтобы узнать, читабелен/писабален/исполнябелен ли данный файл **для данного пользователя**, запускать программу `/usr/bin/test` надо именно от его имени.

---

например, используя программу `/usr/bin/sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
user=$2

for p in r w x; do
  c="-"
  sudo -u "$user" test -$p "$file" && c="$p"
  r=$r$c
done

echo "у пользователя $user имеются права $r на $file"
```

тест:

```
$ ls -l file 
-rw-r--r-x 1 test1 test1 0 Apr 23 17:49 file
$ ./check file test1
у пользователя test1 имеются права rw- на file
$ ./check file ntp
у пользователя ntp имеются права r-x на file
$ ./check file root
у пользователя root имеются права rwx на file
```