# Как вывести в терминал права конкретного пользователя для конкретного файла?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выводить в терминал права доступа(читать/писать/исполнять) к конкретному файлу для конкретно указанного пользователя?
`ls -l` выводит все скопом, а stat выводит только для владельца.
Здесь была подобная тема уже 2 года назад, но по ней выходит ошибка, сейчас это можно как то реализовать? [прошлая подобная тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/817526/358483)
По данному коду выходит постоянно ---, независимо от вводимого пользователя.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
user=$2
for p in r w x; do
  c="-"
  sudo -u "$user" test -$p "$file" && c="$p"
  r=$r$c
done

echo "у пользователя $user имеются права $r на $file"
```

Comment: пакет `sudo` в системе установлен?

Comment: Если такого файла не существет то `"---"` внимательно ищите описку. Или добавьте проверку `e` (что файл существует)

Comment: Пакет sudo установлен. А наличие файла имеется в каталоге.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Требуется тщательно доработать напильником, но как то так:

```bash
check_grant() {
#Возвращаем ошибку если не передан ни один параметр
fileName=${1:?Параметры не могут быть пустыми}
#Если второй параметр пустой то проверяем для текущего пользователя
userName=${2:-`whoami`}

#Проверяем существует ли файл
[[ -e "${fileName}" ]] || { echo "Файл ${fileName} не существует"; return 1; }
#Получаем группы для пользователя
userGroup=`groups ${userName}`

#Получаем данные о файле
IFS=';' read typeFile userFile groupFile access <<< `stat -c "%F;%U;%G;%A" "${fileName}"`
#(НЕверно)на случай если это каталог убираем из прав букву d
#Исключил, так как данный атрибут можно исключить при выборе элементов
if [[ $userFile == $userName ]]; then
    userPriv=${access:1:3}
elif [[ -n `grep -w "${groupFile}" <<< "${userGroup/*:/}"` ]]; then
    userPriv=${access:4:3}
else
    userPriv=${access:7:3}
fi
printf "%-15s | %-20s | %s" "$userName" "`sed 's/---/ без доступа/;s/x/ запуск/;s/r/ чтение/;s/w/ запись/;s/-//g' <<< "${userPriv}"`" "${typeFile} ${fileName}"
}
```

```txt
# check_grant /etc/crontab
root            |  чтение запись       | обычный файл /etc/crontab
```

---

```txt
#check_grant /etc/crontab robot
robot           |  чтение              | обычный файл /etc/crontab
```

Comment: Все работает, все клёво, однако данная функция 2 колонки отображает(т.е у меня под рутом либо чтение и запись, либо чтение и запуск, хотя все 3 входят в права), как это можно подредачить?

Comment: @qwertyqwerty попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое, очень помогли